# can we convert Convert AVAudioTime to Dispatchtime ?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

This is my AvAudioTime

```
AVAudioTime = AVAudioTime(sampleTime: AVAudioFramePosition(beatSampleTime), atRate: bufferSampleRate)
```

How can I convert it to Dispatch time so I can use this with DispatchQueue.main ???